# Devise and helper for custom form builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I created custom form builder for devise sign up form.

Form looks like this, and works fine:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), builder: BootstrapFormBuilder) do |f| 
  <%= f.text_field :username, :autofocus => true %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

Now I want to create helper named `bootstrap_form_for`.
In application helper I wrote (just to test it):

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def bootstrap_form_for(record, options = {}, &block)
    form_for(record, options = {}, &block)
  end
end
```

When instead of `form_for` I insert `bootstrap_form_for` I get error: `undefined method 'users_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f9eb40bc728>:0x007f9eb40bb9b8>` in this `bootstrap_form_for` line.

Error page title: `NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new`

Do you know why?

Comment: If you want to use URL helpers in your module, you might want to include the corresponding module: `include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help :(

Comment: is this helper defined outside of `ApplicationHelper`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was here:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def bootstrap_form_for(record, options = {}, &block)
    form_for(record, options = {}, &block)
  end
end
```

It should be:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def bootstrap_form_for(record, options = {}, &block)
    form_for(record, options, &block)
  end
end
```